# large file attachment via Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, attachment

Below code has been generated and connected to a controller called "streaming" in .net core. The code works well and attaches large files perfectly.

The code needs to be used in another html page to upload files for different purpose. However, when upload button is pressed, below error is displayed:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

This is the case that if I attach a file from the original page, the process gets completed and then I can attach any file from the copied page!
But if I close the browser and try to attach a file from the copied page the error is displayed.

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-app="myApp">
    @*Attachment*@
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div>
                @if (ViewBag.Attachments != null)
                {
                    foreach (var a in ViewBag.Attachments)
                    {
                        var id = @a.AttachmentId;
                        @lastattachid = id;
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 left">
                                <a asp-action="Download" asp-route-path="@a.FilePath\\@a.FileName">@a.FileName</a>
                                <div style=" position: absolute;top: 2px;right: 2px;">
                                    @if (ViewBag.recepient.Equals(@a.CreatedBy))
                                    {
                                        var FilePath = @a.FilePath.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
                                        <a onclick='deleteattachment(@a.AttachmentId, "@a.FileName", "@FilePath")'>✘</a>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input name="attachedfile" type="file" file-model="attachedfile" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <button ng-click="uploadAttachment()">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
</script>

<script>
       var Attachment = (function () {
           function Attachment(customer, invoice, name, dwg, attachedfile) {
               this.attachmentid = @lastattachid + 1;
               this.customer = customer;
               this.jobInv = invoice;
               this.jobName = name;
               this.jobDwg = dwg;
               this.path = "\\@ViewBag.customerId\\" + invoice + ";" + name + ";" + dwg + "\\";
               this.fileName = attachedfile.name;
               this.attachedfile = attachedfile;
           }
           return Attachment;
       }());
```

```
       var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
       myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
           return {
               restrict: 'A',
               link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                   var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                   var modelSetter = model.assign;

                   element.bind('change', function () {
                       scope.$apply(function () {
                           modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                       });
                   });
               }
           };
       }]);
```

```
       myApp.service('attachmentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
           this.uploadAttachment = function (attachment) {
               var fd = new FormData();
               fd.append('AttachmentId', attachment.attachmentid);
               fd.append('Customer', attachment.customer);
               fd.append('JobInv', attachment.jobInv);
               fd.append('JobName', attachment.jobName);
               fd.append('JobDwg', attachment.jobDwg);
               fd.append('Name', attachment.fileName);
               fd.append('Path', attachment.path);
               fd.append('attachedfile', attachment.attachedfile);

               return $http.post('/Streaming/Upload', fd, {
                   transformRequest: angular.identity,
                   headers: {
                       'Content-Type': undefined
                   }
               });
           };
       }]);
```

```
       myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'attachmentService', function ($scope, attachmentService) {
           $scope.uploadAttachment = function () {
               $scope.showUploadStatus = false;
               $scope.showUploadedData = false;

               var attachment = new Attachment("@customerid","@inv", " ", " ", $scope.attachedfile);

               attachmentService.uploadAttachment(attachment).then(function (response) { // success
                   if (response.status === 200) {
                       var inv = "@inv";
                       inv = inv.replace("&amp;", "%26");
                       var job = "@job";
                       job = job.replace("&amp;", "%26");
                       var dwg = "@dwg";
                       dwg = dwg.replace("&amp;", "%26");
                       window.location.href = "/Quote/Details/@ViewBag.customerId?quoteno=" + inv;
                   }
               },
                   function (response) { // failure
                       $scope.uploadStatus = "Attachment upload failed with status code: " + response.status;
                       $scope.showUploadStatus = true;
                       $scope.showUploadedData = false;
                       $scope.errors = [];
                       $scope.errors = parseErrors(response);
                   });
           };
       }]);

       function parseErrors(response) {
           var errors = [];
           for (var key in response.data) {
               for (var i = 0; i < response.data[key].length; i++) {
                   errors.push(key + ': ' + response.data[key][i]);
               }
           }
           return errors;
       }
</script>
```

**Updated:**
Server-side code is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userManager.GetUserName(User)))
        return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Login", controllerName: "Account");

    if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
    {
        return BadRequest($"Expected a multipart request, but got {Request.ContentType}");
    }

    // Used to accumulate all the form url encoded key value pairs in the 
    // request.
    var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();
    string targetFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot\\Attachment";
    string fileName = "";
    var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(Request.ContentType),
        _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
    var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);

    var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
    while (section != null)
    {
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
        var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out contentDisposition);

        if (hasContentDispositionHeader)
        {
            if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFileContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {

                using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(targetFilePath + fileName))
                {
                    await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream);

                    _logger.LogInformation($"Copied the uploaded file '{targetFilePath + fileName}'");
                }
            }
            else if (MultipartRequestHelper.HasFormDataContentDisposition(contentDisposition))
            {
                // Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
                //
                // value

                // Do not limit the key name length here because the 
                // multipart headers length limit is already in effect.
                var key = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentDisposition.Name);
                var encoding = GetEncoding(section);
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(
                    section.Body,
                    encoding,
                    detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
                    bufferSize: 1024,
                    leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    // The value length limit is enforced by MultipartBodyLengthLimit
                    var value = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    value = value.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                    if (String.Equals(value, "undefined", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        value = String.Empty;
                    }
                    formAccumulator.Append(key, value);

                    if (key.Equals("Path"))
                    {
                        targetFilePath += value;
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetFilePath);
                    }
                    if (key.Equals("Name"))
                        fileName = value;
                    if (formAccumulator.ValueCount > _defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidDataException($"Form key count limit {_defaultFormOptions.ValueCountLimit} exceeded.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Drains any remaining section body that has not been consumed and
        // reads the headers for the next section.
        section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
    }

    // Bind form data to a model
    var attachment = new AttachFile();
    var formValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(
        BindingSource.Form,
        new FormCollection(formAccumulator.GetResults()),
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    var bindingSuccessful = await TryUpdateModelAsync(attachment, prefix: "",
        valueProvider: formValueProvider);
    if (!bindingSuccessful)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
    var user = userManager.GetUserName(User);
   // Add attachmnet to a jason file
   // ...
    var uploadedData = new UploadedData()
    {
        Invoice = attachment.JobInv,
        Name = attachment.JobName,
        Dwg = attachment.JobDwg,
        FileName = attachment.FileName,
        FilePath = targetFilePath,
        CreatedBy = user,
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
    };
    return Json(uploadedData);
}


public class AttachFile
{
    public int AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string JobInv { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDwg { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}


public class UploadedData
{
    public string Invoice { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dwg { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? where's the server side code that handles this?

Comment: I really do not understand the purpose with the `var Attachment = (function () {... ` construct ...

Comment: @davidkonrad it creates an object

Comment: @lloyd As long as the data is passed to the "/Streaming/Upload" the rest sgould be alright

Comment: A function, but why wrap it into a self invoking function and declare it twice? Seems to me `function Attachment(customer, invoice, name, dwg, attachedfile) {` would be enough. Anyway, was just curious, not really related to the question.